# Add checkbox with label to a form

Tags: javascript, optimization, form

For a WordPress login form I have written a small plugin. It adds a checkbox with a unique name to the form and if that name is not present in the login POST request it just dies.

The idea is preventing [scripted attacks made for regular WordPress login forms](http://www.metasploit.com/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/wordpress_login_enum).

The PHP code is okay (imho), but I think the JavaScript code looks rather … inelegant. Everything works as expected, it is just not beautiful. What could I improve?

```
<?php  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Unique Log-in Field
 * Description: Adds a checkbox with a unique name to the login form to prevent scripted log-in attempts.
 * Plugin URI:
 * Version:     2013.04.14
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * Licence:     MIT
 * License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

add_action( 'login_init',   't5_unique_login_field' );
add_action( 'login_footer', 't5_unique_login_field' );

/**
 * Add a checkbox with a unique name to the login form.
 *
 * @wp-hook login_init
 * @wp-hook login_footer
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_unique_login_field()
{
    if ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['interim_login'] ) )
        return;

    if ( defined( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT' ) )
        $salt = constant( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT' );
    else
        $salt = filemtime( __FILE__ );

    $unique = md5( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $salt );

    if ( 'POST' === $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] )
    {
        if ( ! isset ( $_POST[ 'log' ] ) )
            return;

        if ( empty ( $_POST[ $unique ] )
            or 'on' !== strtolower( $_POST[ $unique ] )
        )
            exit;

        return;
    }

    ?>
<script>
var unique    = '<?php echo $unique; ?>',
    checkBox  = document.createElement( 'input' ),
    paragraph = document.createElement( 'p' ),
    label     = document.createElement( 'label' ),
    labelText = document.createTextNode( ' I am human' );

checkBox.setAttribute( 'name', unique );
checkBox.setAttribute( 'type', 'checkbox' );
checkBox.setAttribute( 'id',   unique + '_id' );

label.setAttribute( 'for', unique + '_id' );
label.appendChild( checkBox );
label.appendChild( labelText );

paragraph.appendChild( label );
paragraph.setAttribute( 'style', 'clear:both;float:none' );
// get the same font style as the last checkbox
paragraph.setAttribute( 'class', 'forgetmenot' );

document.getElementById( 'loginform' ).appendChild( paragraph );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Screenshots:

Before plugin activation

[image]

After plugin activation

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant to be a comprehensive answer:

If you do not want a bug that happens only in some browsers and only some of the time, use a [safe, conservative format as an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

```
checkBox.setAttribute( 'id',   unique + '_id' );
```

If id is a random 64-bit integer or a GUID in the following form (b362e877-95c3-4e88-99dc-ceb4600639b5), then you would want id to be `'id_' + unique` instead of `unique + '_id'`